# Удаление дублирующих строк c#

Tags: c#

Доброе день, такой вопрос. Есть массив путей к файлам и нужно ,что бы в listbox не добавлялись дублирующие строки. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Не добавлять. Проверить `ListBox1.Items.FindByText` или `ListBox1.Items.FindByValue` перед тем как делать Add

Comment: Вы используете `WPF` или `WinForms`?

Answer (score 6):

Для того, чтобы избежать дублирование нужно сначала аккумулировать информацию в [`HashSet`](http://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level12/12_12.php)

```
HashSet<string> set;
List<string> list;
```

Вариант 1 для небольшого кол-ва строк

```
if (!list.Contains("новая строка")) list.Add("новая строка");
```

Вариант 2 для всего остального

```
if (set.Add("новая строка")) list.Add("новая строка");
```

Comment: А есть пример какой нибудь ?

Comment: @Jeron Приведите пример того как вы наполняете ваш ListBox

Comment: foreach(ex in file) { listbox1.Items.Add(ex); }

Answer (score 1):

```
var dict = arr.Where(str => arr.Count(st => st == str) > 1).Distinct()
```

UPD: var dict = arr.Distinct()

Comment: Это может и ничего, как пример использования Linq, но нет хуже читаемого кода и труднее сопровождаемого, чем Linq. Да и производительностью тут не всё OK.

Comment: Тем не менее задачу я бы решил при помощи такой конструкции. Здесь автором задан вопрос о производительности или поддерживаемости? Может у него задачка в полтора класса умещается, зачем писать портянку с кодом? Уж если и прокомментировали, то аргументируйте.

Comment: Что-то я не пойму, как этот код относится к вопросу. Потому что, насколько я понимаю, надо просто `arr.Distinct()`. И то уже в комментариях сказали, что не подходит.

Comment: "Есть массив путей к файлам" - я отфильтровал бы дубликаты и спокойно заливал бы их в лист бокс. Про arr.Distinct() согласен, тут затупил. Но чем не решение? Или тут конкурс на самый остроумный комментарий?

Comment: @ВалерийГорбунов - такой конкурс здесь идет перманентно :)